# Send message to server java

Tags: java

I'm creating chat program. At first, I send message to server from client and server should get message, but the message is not sent to the server until I shut down client.

*Here is my code:*

**Client:**

```
 private Socket Client;
 private Thread RunClient;
 private JButton Send;
 private int Port=8000;
 private String Host="localhost";

 public void init() {//Here we connecting to server

     Send=new JButton();
     Send.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 15));
     Send.setLocation(575,Text.getHeight()+15);//395
     Send.SetBorderColor(Color.cyan);
     Send.setForeground(Color.white);
     Send.setText("Send");
     Send.setSize(30,70);
     Send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            SendButton_Click(e);
        }

    });
       try
       {
         InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(Host);
         Client = new Socket(address, Port);
         System.out.println("Client started. Port: "+Port+"\n");

       }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("Error:"+e);
       }
   }
public void  SendButton_Click(ActionEvent e) {//Here we sending message to server

    String sendMessage = "hi";
        try {
            sendMessageToServer(Client,sendMessage);//sending message to server
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
       System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+sendMessage);
    }

}
private void sendMessageToServer(Socket socket,String message) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new 
    OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

    writer.write(message);
    writer.flush();
}
```

**Here is server:**

```
 private int Port=8000;
 public void init() {//Here we starting server and starting thread
  try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Port);
            System.out.println("Server on. Port: "+Port+"\n");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
         RunServer = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    ServerLoop();
                }
         };
         RunServer.start();
 }
 public void ServerLoop() {//here we should receive message..
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Server loop");
          try
            {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                    InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new    
                    InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());

                    BufferedReader bufferedreader = new  
                    BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

                    PrintWriter printwriter = new  
                    PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);

                    String line = "";
                    boolean done = false;
                    while (((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) &&(!done)){
                        System.out.println("Received from Client: " + line);

                        if (line.compareToIgnoreCase("Exit") == 0) done = true;
                      }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you formatted your code and followed standard naming conventions.  That said, don't you think it's important for us to see the method `sendMessageToServer`, since you're having trouble sending a message to a server?

Comment: What do you mean "bet server get message when i shut down client..."?  Do you mean ", but instead the server doesn't get the message until I shut down the client.  Con you help me understand why?".  Please clarify your question or it will be closed.

Comment: Sorry forget add function sendMessageToClient... now I edit :)

Comment: I mean, when i press send button when server dont get message, but when i shut down client program, when server receives message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server is waiting for a full line, i.e. a String that is terminated with `\r`, `\n`, or both.  Your client does not send a line ending, thus the server's call to `readLine()` cannot complete until the stream ends, when the remaining (non-line-terminated) input is returned.

Try sending `"hi\n"` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks you helped me... stupid mistake...Just needed close... Writer.close()... Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

The `readLine()` method will wait until it receives a newline character (`\n`) before returning. This means that the method blocks until the client is disconnected. The solution is simple; change the line in `sendMessageToServer()` that is

```
writer.write(message);
```

to

```
writer.write(message  + "\n");
```

However, you will not be able to send the server messages containing `\n` without bugs. To do so, you will have to rewrite your reading code to use character-by-character reading.